# What kind of design is this?

Tags: style-identification, symbolism

i want to design a style, which is classic one and we saw them in movies and old games. I don't know what exactly it is called but i have draw a sketch of it.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please add some more examples? I don't even have a clue what your sketch depicts, let a lone what kind of style it is. Some shots from those movies and games you mention, would be great!

Comment: I was looking for a SCROLL design. i wasn't aware of proper word for it, thats why i added this sketch. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about graphic design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're finding is "scroll".

Comment: I should downvote this as he said he is after an "art style" not an object but somehow I think this is what he actually wants and just worded the question wrong.

Comment: @SaturnsEye Yes. I think so.

Comment: @SaturnsEye do whatever you should feel, but by the question you should know the OP doesn't even know the proper name for the thing he's looking for so you can't blame for `worded the question wrong` :)